# How to set textAlignment for UITableViewHeaderFooterView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I make a UITableViewControl. I need to set `textAlignment` for UITableViewHeaderFooterView as shown below. But it's not working.

[image: TableView control]

```
UITableViewHeaderFooterView *header = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view;
[header.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"]]];
header.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

Comment: It is centered.  The label is not the full width of the header.  I'm guessing you want the text in the middle of the screen?

Comment: It is centered. But now, i want to set header like image! can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a header filled by a stretched image, try to use `contentView` instead of `textLabel`

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return HEADER_HEIGHT;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section {

    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *header = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view;
    UIImage *originImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage"];
    CGSize size = header.frame.size;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    [originImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,size.width,size.height)];
    UIImage* resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    header.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:resizedImage];
}
```

Comment: i want to set stretched image for textLabel. Do you have any solution?

Comment: Thanks you very much! It's working when i set CGRectMake.

Answer (score 1):

Create a view，on this view add a label，and set the view as the header view on your table:

```
self.tableView.headerView = view
```

Comment: Thanks you for supporting!

Comment: [originImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(-95,0,size.width,size.height)];
    UIImage* resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @wg_hij, we can use custom `UIView` as header view for table view.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let sectionInfo = fetchedResultsController!.sections! as [NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo]
    let headerTitle = sectionInfo[section].name

    let headerHeight:CGFloat = tableView.sectionHeaderHeight
    let headerView = HeaderView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.width, headerHeight), withHeaderLable: headerTitle)
    return headerView
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 40;//custom height
}
```

`HeaderView` will be something like:

```
class HeaderView: UIView {

var headerLbl: UILabel?

init(frame: CGRect, withHeaderLable headerText: String) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    makeUpHeaderLabel(headerText)
}

func makeUpHeaderLabel(lblText: String) {
    if headerLbl == nil {
        headerLbl = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10))
        headerLbl!.makeRoundedRect()
        headerLbl!.bgColorName = ColorPaletteCP1
        headerLbl!.fontName = BHTypoMI14
        headerLbl!.textAlignment = .Center
        headerLbl!.baselineAdjustment = .AlignCenters
        addSubview(headerLbl!)
    }
    headerLbl!.text = lblText
    headerLbl!.sizeToFit()
    let frame = headerLbl!.frame
    headerLbl!.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width + 32, frame.height + 8)
    headerLbl!.center = CGPointMake(width / 2, height / 2)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

Using this custom header view, we can do anything related to look-n-feel!

Comment: Thanks you for supporting!